# Multiplying length values

Tags: units, arithmetic

I am trying to make a macro `\scalelen` that scales an existing length value `\len` by the input value. However, `\len` is actually a string containing a unit. I made a code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\len{4ex}
\def\scalelen#1{\numexpr#1*\len\relax}
% \def\scalelen#1{\dimexpr#1*\len\relax}

\noindent
A\hspace{\scalelen{0.5}}B\\
A\hspace{\scalelen{1}}B\\
A\hspace{\scalelen{2}}B

\end{document}
```

[image]

This code works as intended but it throws an error for a scale factor with a decimal point. I found that `\numexpr` works only for integers. How can this be efficiently fixed?

I found that `\def\len{4.0ex}` also throws errors for all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a proper *length*, then you can prefix it with any scalar and it'll stretch as needed. So, instead of `\def\len{4ex}`, use

```
\newlength{\len}
\setlength{\len}{4ex}
```

This now allows you to use `x\len` for any scaler `x`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\newlength{\len}
\setlength{\len}{4ex}
\newcommand{\scalelen}[1]{#1\len}

A\hspace{4ex}B

A\hspace{\scalelen{0.5}}B

A\hspace{\scalelen{1}}B

A\hspace{\scalelen{2}}B

\end{document}
```

If you're stuck on using `\def\len{4ex}`, then you'll need a small workaround:

```
\newcommand{\len}{4ex}
\newcommand{\scalelen}[1]{#1\dimexpr\len}
```

You can, of course, also incorporate [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp) to perform the calculations. It changes all lengths into their `p`oin`t` equivalent (and strips the unit). So,

```
\usepackage{xfp}
\newcommand{\len}{4ex}
\newcommand{\scalelen}[1]{\fpeval{#1*\len}pt}
```

Comment: Wow, this is a thorough answer. I was customizing an existing package, so I had to stick to `\def` for now. Thank you so much!